# Question 2 from Exercises 2.5.1 from F. Mary Hart - Guide to Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The question is $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are two convergent sequences of real numbers such that $(a_n) \rightarrow a $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $(b_n) \rightarrow b $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Prove that, if 
 $(a_n +(-1)^nb_n)$ and $((-1)^{n+1}a_n + b_n)$ both converge, then $a=b=0$.

From comment: I couldn't manage to answer this. The furthest I got was saying that the subsequences of $(a_n + (-1)^n b_n)$ also converge so $(a_n + b_2n)$ converges to $a+b$, and $(a_n + b_(2n+1))$ converges to $(a-b)$ by the algebra of limits. I did this for the second expression too. I did this because the last section of the book was subsequences. I am not sure if this was the correct approach. Can someone lead me towards the right direction?

How would I answer this question?

Comment: That seems to be a question only you can answer.  How would you?

Comment: I couldn't manage to answer this. The furthest I got was saying that the subsequences of (a_n + (-1)^n b_n) also converge so (a_n + b_2n) converge to a+b and (a_n + b_(2n+1)) converge to a-b by the algebra of limits. I did this for the second expression too. I did this because the last section of the book was subsequences. I am not sure if this was the correct approach. Can someone lead me towards the right direction?

Comment: Okay, that's fine, but please include the content of your comment, in your question.  We just want to see your thoughts and/or if you tried anything.  So I will add your comment as "context", okay?

Comment: I've included your comment as context in your question.  Thanks for commenting!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll remember that. This was my first question on here

Comment: No problem.  I just appreciate your response to my comment!  You can't go wrong on this site when you respond to feedback!  Welcome!!

Comment: That's nice to know. Do you have any advice on how to approach and answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one: prove that for all sequences $c$, if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_n$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n c_n$ both exist, then they are both zero.

Step 2: write $(-1)^n b_n = (a_n + (-1)^n b_n) - a_n$, and use this to show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n b_n$ exists. Apply the result in step 1 to $b$.

Step 3: write $(-1)^n a_n = b_n - (b_n + (-1)^{n + 1} a_n$, and use similar reasoning to the above step to find the limit of $a$.

Comment: How would I do step 1? My approach would be that because the first sequence, cn, has the limit a, the even terms (and so the positive terms) of the second term have the same limit because it is a sub sequence of the first sequence. Then because the limit is unique, the limit of the negative terms of the 2nd sequence is the same and so it must be 0.

Comment: I am confused as to how by adding and subtracting an in part 2 will help you show the limit of (-1)^n bn exists. Could you provide some clarity please?

Comment: Is it because we know the first part of the expression is convergent and so is -an? Sorry I have just realised that now, if that is correct.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the right argument. We have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_{2n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^{2n} c_{2n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n c_n$ using the subsequence argument. And we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_{2n + 1} = - \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^{2n + 1} c_{2n + 1} = - \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n c_n$. This means both limits are zero.

Comment: For steps 2 and 3, it is a basic property of how limits interact with differences.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on step 1. For step 2 and 3, are you referring to the limit being equal to the difference between $(a_n + (-1)^n b_n)$ and $(a_n)$ (for part 2) and the same argument for part 3, because we know the limit exists for both expressions.